# How to fix the SMPT error in AWS EC2 Grafana

Tags: smtp, gmail, grafana, alerts, aws-ec2-instance-connect

I have configured an EC2 for Grafana. It's working fine. Then I have configured SMTP to get mail alerts.

```
enter code here

enabled = true
host = smtp.gmail.com:25
user = me@gmail.com
# If the password contains # or ; you have to wrap it with triple quotes. Ex """#password;"""
password = Mypass@$
cert_file =
key_file =
skip_verify = true
from_address = me@gmail.com
from_name = Grafana
```

*Note: This mail do not have 2FA
*Note: Port 25 already opened in security groups of the grafana server

I got the below error:

> Failed to send test alert.: the receiver timed out: failed to send notification to email addresses: me@gmail.com: dial tcp xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:25: i/o timeout

Answer (score 0):

You can not use your true google password when connecting to googles smtp server anymore.  This is due to the removal of the Less secure apps setting.

To find this enable 2fa on your google account and create an apps password.  see [Quick fix for SMTP username and password not accepted error](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_u5KIeXiVI)

If you cant enable 2fa on your google account you will need to switch to using Xoauth2 and request an access token of the user.  see [Configure Google OAuth2 authentication](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/configure-security/configure-authentication/google/)